# char_length alternative for JSON type?

Tags: postgresql

We can use `CHECK` and `char_length` to limit the size of a field of type `TEXT`.

`CHECK (char_length(myField) <= 100)`

How can we limit the size (in bytes or characters) of a field of type `JSON` in a similar way since `char_length` does not work for `JSON` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we limit the size (in bytes or characters) of a field of type
>   JSON in a similar way since char_length does not work for JSON type?

Casting the column `JSON` datatype to varchar is also a option. 
That way you can use the `CHAR_LENGTH` function.

```
CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(myField::varchar) <= 100)
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9R84epPuwh9p2UrcB6NDFS/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pg_column_size` which works for any column type:

```
CHECK (pg_column_size(myField) <= 100)
```

It gives you the size in octets.